# CSS - Jquery : Nested <ul> with different CSS possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently have a web page that has 2 tabs on it. The 2 tabs are created with jquery alongside css.

I want to create a horizontal drop down hover menu when the user scrolls over the tab.

This seems alot easier said then done... I feel like I should simply nest another unordered list in my tab(li). But when I do this. Everything gets jumbled up and my new unordered list that should be my new hover drop down menu turns into tabs.

Is there a way for me to nest a  in another  without the nested  using the tabs CSS and just using the Hover Menu CSS?

Sorry I am very new to this, what i assume is, advanced jquery. Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: post some code for us to look at so we can tell what you're talking about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this article](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/).

> The original Suckerfish Dropdowns article published in A List Apart proved to be a popular way of implementing lightweight, accessible CSS-based dropdown menus that accommodated Internet Explorer by mimicking the :hover pseudo-class.